# opencv object counting standard blob or need AI?

Tags: python, opencv, object-detection

I want to count the profiles in different shape. I think I can do without Deep Learning with blob-detecting or watershed algorithm need the adjustment to accurately counting . than my boss convincing to use modern tech.

simpleblob has some good detection but watershell total failure.
How can I count this objects %100 accuracy

codes: Simpleblob:

```
    import cv2
import numpy as np;

# Read image
im = cv2.imread("/Users/tulpar/Desktop/Screen Shot 2023-04-25 at 15.16.24.png", cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
im = cv2.resize(im, (1440, 880))

# Setup SimpleBlobDetector parameters.
params = cv2.SimpleBlobDetector_Params()

# Change thresholds
params.minThreshold = 10 #10
params.maxThreshold = 150   #200

# Filter by Area.
params.filterByArea = True # True
params.minArea = 500 #1500

# Filter by Circularity
params.filterByCircularity = True #True
params.minCircularity = 0.5 #0.1

# Filter by Convexity
params.filterByConvexity = True #True
params.minConvexity = 0.87 #0.87

# Filter by Inertia
params.filterByInertia = True #True
params.minInertiaRatio = 0.0 #0.01

# Create a detector with the parameters
ver = (cv2.__version__).split('.')
if int(ver[0]) < 3:
    detector = cv2.SimpleBlobDetector(params)
else:
    detector = cv2.SimpleBlobDetector_create(params)

# Detect blobs.
keypoints = detector.detect(im)

# Draw detected blobs as red circles.
# cv2.DRAW_MATCHES_FLAGS_DRAW_RICH_KEYPOINTS ensures
# the size of the circle corresponds to the size of blob
total_count = 0
for i in keypoints:
    total_count = total_count + 1


im_with_keypoints = cv2.drawKeypoints(im, keypoints, np.array([]), (0, 0, 255), cv2.DRAW_MATCHES_FLAGS_DRAW_RICH_KEYPOINTS)

# Show blobs
cv2.imshow("Keypoints", im_with_keypoints)
cv2.waitKey(0)

print(total_count)
```

watershed:

```
[import cv2
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
# Load the image
img = cv2.imread("/Users/tulpar/Desktop/profil_01.png")


gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# Apply thresholding to create a binary image
ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(gray,0,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
# Apply morphological opening to remove noise
kernel = np.ones((3,3),np.uint8)
opening = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh,cv2.MORPH_OPEN,kernel,iterations=2)

# Find sure background using dilated image
sure_bg = cv2.dilate(opening,kernel,iterations=3)

# Find sure foreground using distance transform and apply threshold
dist_transform = cv2.distanceTransform(opening,cv2.DIST_L2,5)
thresh_dist = cv2.threshold(dist_transform, 0.7*dist_transform.max(), 255, 0)\[1\]
sure_fg = np.uint8(thresh_dist)

# Find unknown region
unknown = cv2.subtract(sure_bg,sure_fg)

# Apply watershed algorithm to separate objects
markers = cv2.connectedComponents(sure_fg)\[1\]
markers += 1
markers\[unknown==255\] = 0
markers = cv2.watershed(img,markers)

# Count the number of objects
num_objects = len(np.unique(markers)) - 1
print(f"Number of objects found: {num_objects}")

# Display the results
img\[markers == -1\] = \[255,0,0\] # Mark the boundary regions with blue color
cv2.imshow('Objects', img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()][1]
```

[test1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xrmge.jpg)

[cantFind object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qh10B.png)

[test2 here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yZRbV.png)